Check whether a string contains a specific word and change it
i am a magnitologist and i am trying to make automation of the routine problem using python. Now i work with the file :
with open('test3.txt') as file:
    my_list = file.readlines()  
    b = [line.strip() for line in my_list]

as a result, i get a list with many elements(strings):
['"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest`.png",', '"httpVersion": "http/2.0",', '"headers": [', '{', '"name": ":authority",', '"value": "services.swpc.noaa.gov"', '},', '{', '"name": ":method",', '"value": "HEAD"', '},', '{', '"name": ":path",', '"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest`.png"', '"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/`latest`.png",', '"httpVersion": "http/2.0",', '"headers": [', '{', '"name": ":authority",', '"value": "services.swpc.noaa.gov"', '},', '{', '"name": ":method",', '"value": "HEAD"', '},', '{', '"name": ":path",', '"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/`latest`.png"', '},', '{', '"name": ":scheme",', '"value": "https"', '},', '{', '"name": "accept",', '"value": "*/*"', '},', '{', '"name": "accept-encoding",', '"value": "gzip, deflate, br"', '', '']

my task is to find all the lines containing latest and change this specific word, like this :
'"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest1`.png",'

the next string containing latestshould look like:
'"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest2`.png"', '

etc , in essence, i just need to add 1 to the word "latest" every time, but i break my head over  it for 2 days) please help
here is my "code" but it does not work:
with open('test3.txt') as file:
    my_list = file.readlines()  
    b = [line.strip() for line in my_list]
    latest_count = 1
    latest_count2 = 2 
for i in range(len(b)):
     if b[i] ==  '"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/latest.png",':
        b[i] =   f'"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/latest{latest_count}.png",'
        latest_count += 1
     elif b[i] == '"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/latest.png"':
          b[i] = f'"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/latest{latest_count2}.png"'
          latest_count2 = 2
print(b)

especially in the original file of thousands of such lines, and they are all different except that they contain latest

First thing first - how is this test3.txt obtained? Looks like output from curl?

its from Development Console

original file in .har format ,       i just created   test3.text  and copied into it a couple of values from original file wich i got from Development Console

It looks like a JSON file, except it's missing the { and } around the top-level object. You could try adding those and then use json.loads() to parse it into a dictionary.

IIUC, you can do:
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    cnt = 1
    for line in f_in:
        if "latest" in line:
            line = line.replace("latest", f"latest{cnt}")
            cnt += 1
        print(line.strip())

Prints:
"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest1`.png",
"httpVersion": "http/2.0",
"headers": [
{
"name": ":authority",
"value": "services.swpc.noaa.gov"
},
{
"name": ":method",
"value": "HEAD"
},
{
"name": ":path",
"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/north-pole/d-rap/`latest2`.png"
"url": "https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/`latest3`.png",
"httpVersion": "http/2.0",
"headers": [
{
"name": ":authority",
"value": "services.swpc.noaa.gov"
},
{
"name": ":method",
"value": "HEAD"
},
{
"name": ":path",
"value": "/images/animations/d-rap/global_f05/d-rap/`latest4`.png"
},
{
"name": ":scheme",
"value": "https"
},
{
"name": "accept",
"value": "*/*"
},
{
"name": "accept-encoding",
"value": "gzip, deflate, br"



I suggest you check for /`latest`.png, so you don't accidentally do the replacement in something like latest.noaa.gov

Maybe the code below can help you out:
def update_latest(lst):
    count_latest = 0
    updated_list = []

    for item in lst:
        if "latest" in item:
            count_latest += 1
            updated_list.append("latest{}{}".format(count_latest, item[6:]))
        else:
            updated_list.append(item)

    return updated_list

updated_list = update_latest(b)
print(updated_list)

For instance, given the input list ["latestsjfgjhgf", "wyrt", "latestfgjhgf"], the function above yields ['latest1sjfgjhgf', 'wyrt', 'latest2fgjhgf'].
Hope this helped! And may the code be with you...
